# Как добавить boost thread через cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, boost

Не могу понять как подтянуть бинарь буста через cmake, заголовки подключаются, но бинарь не находится, что я написал неправильно? В данном примере пытаюсь добавить boost thread.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(test3)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -pthread")
find_package(Boost 1.74.0 REQUIRED)
include_directories(thread ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(test3 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test3 ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: вот тут в конце доки по бусту приведен пример, как его включать. пример сложнее, там используется переменная Boost_FOUND. Может, этот пример Вам поможет? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы вызываете `find_package(Boost)` эта команда находит только хидер-онли библиотеки. `boost::thread` не хидер-онли, так что вам нужно прописать, что вы ищете этот компонент: `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread)`